# What is the kafka? Is it a data storing server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Is kafka a data storing server?

As i understand, in example,

A user bought a item in game client.

Game server store the purchase log.

And the game server send the data to kafka server through kafka producer.

Kafka store these data and send via consumer to server which needs purchase log.

Is it alright?

I can't understand concept of kafka.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka is a Message Bus and/or Queue.

Producers can send data to the bus. Consumers can subscribe to specific topics in order to receive those messages as producer sends them to the bus.

And as you understood correctly it is also possible for consumers to receive old messages from the queue.

Messages are plain text – that means, you have to take care of serializing and deserializing them in your applications or services.